# Import Excel 2010 to Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, excel

I am using Excel 2010 and sql server 2008 to import the data from excel to sql server. But am unsuccessful. Can you please check the way i am doing ?

```
sp_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options',1
RECONFIGURE
GO

sp_CONFIGURE 'optimize for ad hoc workloads',1
RECONFIGURE
GO

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE


SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\anayak\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Book1.xlsx; HDR=YES;IMEX=1','SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]');
```

where i am getting this error

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

I installed the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable for Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.

But when i use the command  "ODBCAD32.EXE" to check the version of my excel then i am getting 14.00.4760.1000.

Then i tried my connection string to -

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0','Excel 14.0;Database=C:\Users\anayak\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Book1.xlsx; HDR=YES;IMEX=1','SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]');
```

but again it didnt work.

Can you please suggest what i am doing wrong here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the OS name you are using

Comment: windows 7 32 bit and sql server 2008 32 bit..

Comment: Try turning off the UAC.

Comment: Still the same error ... i wanted to know how it is linked ?

Comment: I have faced the same problem last month so I thought that could work

Answer (score 0):

**Re: 7303 error**

[Distributed Queries in SQL Server, data from XLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530708/distributed-queries-in-sql-server-data-from-xls/25188298#25188298)

So your main error is likely this;

```
OLE DB provider "MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

I would check some permissions.

Check the permissions on the Temp folder

This is needed because the provider uses the temp folder while retrieving the data. The folder can be one of the below based on whether you use a local system account or network domain account.

For network accounts, folder is

**\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp**

and for local system account its \Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Temp

Right click on this folder and give it read write access to the account (or group) executing the code.  That solved the error for me.

Also

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/07/23/ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-for-linked-server-null-returned-message-unspecified-error.aspx

This is because the SQL Server Service is trying to write the temp DSN to the temp folder for the login that started the service, in this case the Admin/Admin login.
The temp folder is something like: **C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Local Settings\Temp**
.15 As mentioned, the OleDbProvider will always execute in the context of the user who initialized it, in this case User/User.
.16 User/User has no rights on this folder (**C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Local Settings\Temp**).
If running FileMon when the SQL is executed, we can see the following:
(Actually, try using **Process Monitor - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645**)

sqlservr.exe:000         QUERY INFORMATION        C:\DOCUME~1\Admini~1\LOCALS~1\Temp   ACCESS DENIED            Attributes: Error

So to summarize so far:
The SQL Server service is started as Admin/Admin, when the select is made, the OleDb provider is invoked by User/User.
Now the OleDb provider attempts to create a temporary DSN in the temp directory. This will be the temp directory for the SQL Server service (Admin/Admin)
but the user (in this case User/User)  does not have write permissions on this folder. And the error occurs.

There are two ways to resolve this.

**Option 1**:
Log out of the machine and log in as the account that starts the SQL Server Service (in this case Admin/Admin) then start a command prompt
and type “set t” (no quotes),  this will show something like:

TEMP=C:\DOCUME~1\Admin\LOCALS~1\Temp
TMP=C:\DOCUME~1\Admin\LOCALS~1\Temp

these are the environment variables set for %TEMP% and %TMP%, so go to that folder and right click and select Properties -> Security,
then add the user, in this case User/User, note that the default for the user is Read&Execute/List Folder Content/Read, this not enough, you have to select Write as well.

Log out, and log in again as User/User and rerun the command from SSMS. This time it should work.

**Option 2**:
Log on as Admin and change the TEMP and TMP variable to, for example, C:\Temp, basically this moves the Temp directory out of the Documents and Settings folder.
However, you must restart the SQL server for this to take effect.

So basically, what happens is that when SQL Server starts, it uses the Temp folder of the startup account (Admin/Admin) but the MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0 will always execute
as the user who calls the SQL command (User/User) and this will fail unless this user does not have Write access to that temp folder.

Without knowing all setups out there, perhaps option 2 is the preferred solution since with option 1, you will have to add ALL the users that will invoke the provider which may not be practical.
Also, when changing the startup account for the SQL Server service, then the TEMP directory for that account will be used, and you will see the error again until you, again, give write permissions for  all the users on this TEMP folder...or a user group (preferred).